# How to install respond.js in bootstrap 3 in a Rails 4 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to migrate from Bootstrap 2.3.2 to 3.0 for my rails 4 app.

Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of Respond.js to enable media query support.

How do I install Respond.js in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [respond-rails](https://github.com/gevans/respond-rails) gem, which vendors the respond.js library.

To install you must first add this line to your gemfile:

```
gem "respond-rails", "~> 1.0"
```

Then, add this to your application layout:

```
<%= respond_include_tags %>
```

Additionally, you may like to add this line to your `production.rb` file:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( modernizr.js respond.js respond-proxy.html respond.proxy.js )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that respond-rails is serving respond 1.0, whereas respond is now sitting at 1.4.2.